# Android Add Delay After Menu Item Selection

Tags: java, android

I'm making a simple game for Android, basically the player makes a move and the computer makes a move back, with the game checking if there is a winner after each turn. What's been happening is that when there is a winner, it refreshes and goes back to a clear board. I want it to pause for a few seconds to allow the user to see the game results after making a move, however, every time I use Thread.sleep(3000), it pauses in the menu (meaning, you tap your move and the menu stays up for 3 seconds, then does your move) instead of showing the game and pausing so the user can see what happened before refreshing.

Here are some pieces of my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.moves, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    String move = item.getTitle().toString();
    if(item.getTitle().toString().equals("Quit")){
        finish();
    }

    //Handle all other moves
    if(isWinner())
        refreshBoard();
        //Here is where I want to pause for a bit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Thread.sleep` in another thread?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}).start();
```